# Changing the title of a YouTube video that's been uploaded

Tags: youtube

How do you change the title of a YouTube video after it's been uploaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sign in to YouTube and go to [your videos](http://www.youtube.com/my_videos)

- Click Edit
- Change Title
- Save Changes

Comment: I see at that link to the right of the video there's an edit option.